# Create a custom Model Binder for a custom type

Tags: asp.net-core

In an ASP.NET CORE 1.1 project I have the following model:

```
public class GetProductsModel {
  public OrderExpression OrderBy { get; set; }
}
```

OrderExpression is a class which has the following method:

```
Boolean TryParse(String value, out OrderExpression expression)
```

The method creates a `OrderExpression` instance from a `String` and can be used:

```
OrderExpression expression;

Boolean parsed = OrderExpression.TryParse(value, out expression);
```

How can I create a custom Model Binder to properties of type `OrderExpression`?

Comment: Are you trying to bind properties of OrderExpression or are you trying to bind an OrderExpression to an input to a controller/action, which would be a string input then map to an OrderExpression object?

Comment: @AshleyLee I am trying to bind an OrderExpression to an input of a controller action ... Does this help?

Comment: @MiguelMoura, just wondering if you had a chance to try my proposed solution?

Comment: @DanielJ.G. Yes, just did it ... I marked it as the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume that within your request data there is a property `orderBy` that you want to bind into an `OrderExpression` using `OrderExpression.TryParse`.

Let's assume your `OrderExpression` class looks like follows, where I have provided a very simple implementation of your `TryParse` method:

```
public class OrderExpression
{
    public string RawValue { get; set; }
    public static bool TryParse(string value, out OrderExpression expr)
    {
        expr = new OrderExpression { RawValue = value };
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then you could create a model binder which basically gets the raw string value and calls `OrderExpression.TryParse`:

```
public class OrderExpressionBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {            
        var values = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        if (values.Length == 0) return Task.CompletedTask;

        // Attempt to parse
        var stringValue = values.FirstValue;
        OrderExpression expression;
        if (OrderExpression.TryParse(stringValue, out expression))
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(bindingContext.ModelName, expression, stringValue);
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(expression);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

You will also need a new model binder provider, which returns your new binder just for the `OrderExpression` type:

```
public class OrderExpressionBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        return context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(OrderExpression) ? new OrderExpressionBinder() : null;
    }
}

// It should be registered in your Startup class, adding it to the ModelBinderProviders collection:
services.AddMvc(opts => {
    opts.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new OrderExpressionBinderProvider());
});
```

With this in place, you will be able to bind `OrderExpression` parameters of the controller actions. Something like in the following example:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Products([FromBody]OrderExpression orderBy) 
{
    return Ok();
}

$.ajax({
    method: 'POST', 
    dataType: 'json', 
    url: '/home/products', 
    data: {orderby: 'my orderby expression'}
});
```

However there is something else that needs to be done for you to be able to send a json and bind it to a complex model like `GetProductsModel` which internally contains an `OrderExpression`. I am talking about a scenario like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Products([FromBody]GetProductsModel model)
{
    return Ok();
}

public class GetProductsModel
{
    public OrderExpression OrderBy { get; set; }
}

$.ajax({
    method: 'POST', 
    dataType: 'json', 
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 
    url: '/home/products', 
    data: JSON.stringify({orderby: 'my orderby expression'})
});
```

In that scenario ASP.Net Core will just use Newtonsoft.Json as the InputFormatter and convert the received json into an instance of the `GetProductsModel` model, without trying to use the new `OrderExpressionBinderProvider` for the internal property.

Luckily, you can also tell Newtonsoft.Json how to format properties of `OrderExpression` type by creating your JsonConverter:

```
public class OrderExpressionJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(OrderExpression);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var stringValue = reader.Value?.ToString();
        OrderExpression expression;
        if (OrderExpression.TryParse(stringValue, out expression))
        {
            return expression;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Which should be registered in your Startup class:

```
services.AddMvc(opts => {
    opts.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new OrderExpressionBinderProvider());

}).AddJsonOptions(opts => {
    opts.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new OrderExpressionJsonConverter());
});
```

Now you will finally be able to handle both scenarios :)