# Prevent validation of a specific type in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I've started to get `InsufficientExecutionStackException` in my ASP.NET Core MVC application.

[image: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation stack]

```
[HttpPost]
public void Update([FromBody] MyModel model)
{
}

class MyModel
{
    public MyData Data { get; set; }
}
```

I've tracked the problem to a custom struct where the Property `Modified` is the one being iterated.

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(MyDataJsonConverter))]
public partial struct MyData
{
    public MyData Modified => new MyData(...)
}
```

The `MyDataJsonConverter` serialize the `MyData` into a single string.

**How can I stop the ValidationVisitor from iterating `MyData`?**

I've tried implementing a custom `IBinderModel` for `MyData` [according to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42493516/33236), but since that isn't the main model but a property type it's never called. 
Adding `[ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(MyDataBinder))]` to the `MyData` struct or properties of its type have no effect.

**Is there something similar to `JsonIgnore` for MVC model binding?**

Adding `[JsonIgnore]` to the property `Modified` have no effect.

[`[BindNever]` doesn't work by design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922133/why-bindnever-attribute-doesnt-work) when using `[FromBody]`.

The problem is the the stack overflow during validation. Serialization works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the cause of your problem completely, but since you asked for an alternative  to `JsonIgnore`, there is the `IgnoreDataMemberAttribute`, it is even supported by newtonsoft, but newer asp.net core versions don't support it.

now what i did and you can do, is register newtonsoft to handle json in the `Startup.cs`:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors();
        services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
        services.AddDbContext<SampleContext>(builder => builder.UseInMemoryDatabase("SampleDb"));
        ....
    }
```

so then you can still use `JsonIgnore` or `IgnoreDataMemberAttribute`

Comment: I tried `[IgnoreDataMemeber]` but it strangely locked up Visual Studio, no crash, no "Not responding", only not responding until I force closed my program it was running.

Comment: I'm using Newtonsoft.Json for serialization and that works as expected.

Comment: oh sorry, i completely forgot, you have to have this package [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson/), but I'm not sure thats your problem cause it shouldn't break that hard

Answer (score 0):

Validation can be disabled by type by adding `SuppressChildValidationMetadataProvider` to MVC options.

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {    
        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.ModelMetadataDetailsProviders.Add(
                new SuppressChildValidationMetadataProvider(
                    typeof(MyData)
                )
            );
        });
    }
}
```